# Elasticsearch - Search Term is broken down and pulls unwanted results

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

If a search query is 'elasticsearch', it pulls documents which has content 'search'.

Example -

```
 {"query":{"bool" : {"should": [{
            "match" : { "title" : "cocacola" }
        }]}}}
```

This query pulls documents containing title - 'cola' too.

How can i avoid those documents from appearing.

Comment: Could you post your Mapping and your Indexing Document?

Comment: That was a mapping issue. Thanks man.